# Difference between "ppa-purge" and "add-apt-repository -r"?

Tags: ppa, add-apt-repository

What is the main difference between `ppa-purge` and `add-apt-repository -r`. Which one better clear residual items and reason to use one over another? 
Does `add-apt-repository -r` should do what `ppa-purge` do?

Edit: Also do both remove key from apt's keyring?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

For what I understand, the difference is what they do **after** removing the PPA.

**ppa-purge** - Disables a PPA and reverts to the official packages if applicable. For example, if I added the xorg-edgers PPA and installed the Nvidia drivers, if I do a `ppa-purge` on said PPA, it would not only disable the xorg-edgers PPA but also revert the NVIDIA drivers from the one in the PPA to the official ones found on the official Ubuntu repositories.

**add-apt-repository -r** - Will only remove the said PPA. Will not revert any packages.

The case scenarios might be:

- When you want to keep a package from a PPA but want to remove the actual PPA. For example, if you wanted to add the Ubuntu Tweak Package from a PPA but then wanted to remove the PPA, you would use **add-apt-repository** which will leave Ubuntu Tweak installed.
- When you want to go back to an official package and stop using a PPA that has updated/experimental packages (Like Kernel version packages, Proprietary packages...). In this cases you might want to use **ppa-purge** assuming your intention is to go back to the official versions. Which is the same as removing each PPA package installed and then doing:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update  
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo apt-get install PACKAGES
  ```

For most cases, **add-apt-repository** should be enough to add and remove PPAs. The use of **ppa-purge** can only help in the small cases where you want to actually remove a package and install the official version which is not common since most user add a PPA to have something better than the one that comes with Ubuntu. Cases like kazam (From Kazam PPA), Proprietary Video drivers (From swat-x or xorg-edgers PPA), and even the Google Chrome and VirtualBox ones. And even if they remove it, it is only 2 or 3 commands to remove the current packages from the removed PPA and install the official ones.

With all of this in mind, it simply comes down to what the user wants to do about the packages related to the PPA.

Comment: Does that mean that there is no need of `ppa-purge` if I use a repo to install pkg that is not available in official repo, say like "ubuntu-tweak", since there is no pkg to revert to official pkg?

Comment: @Alinwndrld Will update answer.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado Minor spelling mistake: `sudo apt-get ugprade` :)

Comment: @Alinwndrld At least development version of `ppa-purge` removes the packages in that case. You could also test [my version](https://code.launchpad.net/~jarnos/ppa-purge/+git/ppa-purge/+ref/master) of `ppa-purge`, which includes many improvements. It can also remove  other repositories than PPAs, so maybe it would be better to call it `remove-apt-repository`.

Comment: Updated link of the above comment [here](https://launchpad.net/~jarnos/+archive/ubuntu/ppa-purge).

Answer (score 12):

The `apt-add-repository` manpage says this about the command:

```
   REPOSITORY can  be  either  a  line  that  can  be  added  directly  to
   sources.list(5),  in the form ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> for adding Personal
   Package Archives, or a distribution component to enable.

   In  the   first   form,   REPOSITORY   will   just   be   appended   to
   /etc/apt/sources.list.

   In  the second form, ppa:<user>/<ppa-name> will be expanded to the full
   deb  line  of  the  PPA  and   added   into   a   new   file   in   the
   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/  directory.   The  GPG public key of the newly
   added PPA will also be downloaded and added to apt's keyring.

   In the third form, the given distribution component will be enabled for
   all sources.
```

and:

```
-r, --remove Remove the specified repository
```

So `add-apt-repository` just adds and removes lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

The `ppa-purge` manpage says this:

```
NAME
       ppa-purge - disables a PPA and reverts to official packages

DESCRIPTION
       This script provides a  bash  shell  script  capable  of  automatically
       downgrading all packages in a given PPA back to the ubuntu versions.

       You  have  to  run  it  using  root  privileges  because of the package
       manager.
```

So `ppa-purge` will not only remove a PPA, it will also downgrade any packages back to their default versions. This is useful when testing beta or newer versions of software.

Comment: Does both remove ppa key from apt's keyring?

Comment: @Alinwndrld It should.

Comment: @Alinwndrld see [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/675258/21005). As for `ppa-purge`, currently not. Are the keys harmful there?