# Running 12.04 but installed from Vivid Vervet PPA by mistake

Tags: 12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). I made the mistake of adding as a source the gnome3-staging PPA intended for Vivid Vervet, and this has caused some problems when I upgrade.

Although I have already removed this PPA from the sources list, the problem persists, so that there is always an error for 'unmet dependencies'.
How can I solve this situation? Also, I want to remove from my system those Vivid Vervet packages which I had installed.
Thank you

Comment: How did you remove this PPA. Also you can think of [recreating](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) the sources.lst for 12.04 and using it before your upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

First you should remove the added repository. use `ppa-purge` [Difference between "ppa-purge" and "add-apt-repository -r"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/309966/difference-between-ppa-purge-and-add-apt-repository-r)

> ppa-purge - Disables a PPA and reverts to the official packages if
>   applicable. For example, if I added the xorg-edgers PPA and installed
>   the Nvidia drivers, if I do a ppa-purge on said PPA, it would not only
>   disable the xorg-edgers PPA but also revert the NVIDIA drivers from
>   the one in the PPA to the official ones found on the official Ubuntu
>   repositories.

Now after purging the added repository then update software list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then do upgrade

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But you have to notice that you may still need to downgrade some packages manually. To downgrade a package you can use the command:

```
 sudo apt-get install pkg_name=version
```