# How to purge Steam ppa completely

Tags: apt, package-management, games, ppa, steam

I have already purged Steam using apt-get. But I found some PPAs that I added when I installed Steam back then still exist. My questions are:

1. how to completely remove the PPAs related to Steam and
2. Is removing the PPAs enough to purge Steam from my system completely?

I listed the PPAs I added before using this command:

```
grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

and here's part of the result:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.distUpgrade:deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.distUpgrade:deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/steam.list.save:deb-src [arch=amd64,i386] http://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ precise steam
```

How can I remove them? I tried ppa-purge by typing:

```
sudo ppa-purge steam
```

and it gives me the output:

```
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: steam ppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: steam ppa
```

So what is wrong here?

Here's another question regarding the function of the PPAs stored in the directory `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Can I delete them directly? I manually removed some using this command but don't know if this is a good way to clean up:

```
sudo rm -i private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list.distUpgrade private-ppa.launchpad.net_commercial-ppa-uploaders_steam_ubuntu.list.save
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , you can manually remove steam related PPA file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and related gpgkey from `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`.

or 
you can remove using command

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:???/???
```

see my another answer [how to remove PPA completely](https://askubuntu.com/a/675280/432559).

it will remove only steam PPA . if you want remove steam related package then you have to uninstall that packages.