# How do I revert back from sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa?

Tags: 16.10

I tried to upgrade graphics by running following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However, it caused me a serious problem loading the OS. How do I rollback these changes?

Comment: Read the last paragraph of "PPA description" at https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Comment: Use `ppa-purge`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ppa-purge` as suggested on [their launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

> ** Please use ppa-purge to remove this PPA. It is *particularly* recommended to do this before upgrading to a new ubuntu release! **

Thus, we'll install `ppa-purge` package:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers
```

#### What `ppa-purge` do ?

> **ppa-purge** - Disables a PPA and reverts to the official packages if applicable. For example, if I added the xorg-edgers PPA and installed the Nvidia drivers, if I do a ppa-purge on said PPA, it would not only disable the xorg-edgers PPA but also revert the NVIDIA drivers from the one in the PPA to the official ones found on the official Ubuntu repositories.

<sub>Quotes from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/309973/253251) answer.</sub>